# WPF ListView with CollectionViewSource not getting SelectedItem in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I Have a ListView I am grouping using a CollectionViewSource,  but I cant seem to get the selected item back into the ViewModel.  What do I need to do to get the item the user selects?
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComparatorGroupItem}"  does not appear to work when using a collectionviewSource, I tried IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" but that did not help.

```
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="NumberGroups"
                                              Source="{Binding Path=ComparatorGroupItemList}">
                            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Group" />
                            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                        </CollectionViewSource>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <ListView x:Name="lvNumbers"
                              DataContext="{StaticResource NumberGroups}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding IsAsync=True}"
                              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComparatorGroupItem}"
                              VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"
                              VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                              VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True">           
                          
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Number" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Number}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="# Found" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NumberFound}"/>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                        <ListView.GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle>
                                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate>
                                                    <Expander IsExpanded="False">
                                                        <Expander.Header>
                                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                                                           Margin="3"
                                                                           FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"
                                                                           />
                                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}"
                                                                           Margin="3"
                                                                           FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"
                                                                           />
                                                            </StackPanel>
                                                        </Expander.Header>
                                                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                                                    </Expander>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                            </GroupStyle>
                        </ListView.GroupStyle>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
```

Comment: What's `SelectedComparatorGroupItem`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set the `DataContext` of the `ListView` to your local `CollectionViewSource`.  That means that binding `SelectedItem` to `SelectedComparatorGroupItem` is going to look for the `SelectedComparatorGroupItem` property on the `CollectionViewSource`, *not* your viewmodel.  You should be seeing some kind of binding error in the output window from that.

Don't set the `DataContext`, just let it flow through naturally. All you should need to do is bind the `ItemsSource` to the `CollectionViewSource`.

I *think* this will do it, but I don't have VS open, or access to your ViewModel, to verify:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvNumbers"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource NumberGroups}, IsAsync=True}"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComparatorGroupItem}"
    VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"
    VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
    VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True">
```

As a general rule, if you are ever setting the `DataContext` of something, you are not doing the way WPF wants you to do it.  Usually the only place I end up setting it is when I am being lazy with a `UserControl`.

Comment: Thanks, was throwing this together to test a plug in I'm building.  Got code blind!